# Is there a way to write an HTTP request and then execute it at a later time using Flurl?

Tags: c#, flurl

I am trying to write a Flurl HTTP request that will be executed at a later time.

Here is what I would like to do (C# code):

```
public async void SomeFunction(string url, object someJson, object someUrlEncodedData)
{
    var exampleRequest1 = url.PostJsonAsync(someJson);
    var exampleRequest2 = url.PostUrlEncodedAsync(someUrlEncodedData);
    //The two lines above instantly get executed, but that's not what I want. 
    //I want them to "wait" until I run some execute command (see below).

    var exampleResult1 = await exampleRequest1.Execute();
    var exampleResult2 = await exampleRequest2.Execute();
    //The "Execute()" function doesn't exist, but what I want is some other 
    //function that sends the request to the URL and then gets the result.
}
```

Is there a way to do what I wrote in the code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Your requests can be encapsulated in lambdas so their actual execution can be deferred:

```
Func<Task<IFlurlResponse>> req1 = () => url.PostJsonAsync(someJson);
Func<Task<IFlurlResponse>> req2 = () => url.PostUrlEncodedAsync(someUrlEncodedData);
```

Then simply call them when you need to, e.g. `await req1()`, or if your execute method needs to be more elaborate you can wrap it in a helper method like this:

```
async Task<???> ExecuteAsync(Func<Task<IFlurlResponse>> request) {
  var response = await request();
  // do something with the IFlurlResponse?
}
```